# Add seconds and microseconds to datetime if they are not set

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have following datetime:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 15, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

How can I add seconds and microsends to it with python code? So it has the same structure as:

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 18, 15, 31, 21, 436248, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Comment: Do you want to add a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)? Or are you looking for [datetime.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace)? Including something you tried / a specific error to the question would clarify I think.

Comment: Also, it is unclear to me what "*if they are not set*" means - what if they are deliberately set to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use timedelta for that. For example

```
from datetime import timedelta
dt = datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 15, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

if not dt.second:
    dt = dt + timedelta(seconds=21)
if not dt.microsecond:
    dt = dt + timedelta(microseconds=23)
```

Comment: How can check if they are not already set? I don't want to overwrite datetimes who do have the specs

Comment: This did not solve it. After this there is still no seconds filled in..

Comment: can you paste me the datetime value here. The exact one

Comment: datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 15, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

Comment: movement_datetime + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=0) will add 0 microseconds and not add it to the object I think..

Comment: you have to do this I guess `movement_datetime = movement_datetime + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=23)`

Comment: you have to reassign the value to movement_datetime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238606/discussion-between-sg-sg94-and-anand-tripathi).

Comment: solved my problem by giving 1